# Python how can I do a multithreading/asynchronous HTTP server with twisted

Tags: python, multithreading, http, server, twisted

Now I wrote ferver by this tutorial:
https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/web/howto/web-in-60/asynchronous-deferred.html
But it seems to be good only for delayng process, not actually concurently process 2 or more requests. My full code is:

```
from twisted.internet.task import deferLater
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.web.server import Site, NOT_DONE_YET
from twisted.internet import reactor, threads
from time import sleep


class DelayedResource(Resource):
    def _delayedRender(self, request):
        print 'Sorry to keep you waiting.'
        request.write("<html><body>Sorry to keep you waiting.</body></html>")
        request.finish()

    def make_delay(self, request):
        print 'Sleeping'
        sleep(5)
        return request


    def render_GET(self, request):
        d = threads.deferToThread(self.make_delay, request)
        d.addCallback(self._delayedRender)
        return NOT_DONE_YET

def main():
    root = Resource()
    root.putChild("social", DelayedResource())
    factory = Site(root)
    reactor.listenTCP(8880, factory)
    print 'started httpserver...'
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But when I passing 2 requests console output is like:

*Sleeping*

*Sorry to keep you waiting.*

*Sleeping*

*Sorry to keep you waiting.*

But if it was concurrent it should be like:

*Sleeping*

*Sleeping*

*Sorry to keep you waiting.*

*Sorry to keep you waiting.*

So the question is how to make twisted not to wait until response is finished before processing next? 
Also `make_delay`IRL is a large function with heavi logic. Basically I spawn lot of threads and make requests to other urls and collecting results intro response, so it can take some time and not easly to be ported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twisted processes everything in one event loop. If somethings blocks the execution, it also blocks Twisted. So you have to prevent blocking calls.

In your case you have `time.sleep(5)`. It is blocking. You found the better way to do it in Twisted already: `deferLater()`. It returns a `Deferred` that will continue execution after the given time and release the events loop so other things can be done meanwhile. In general all things that return a deferred are good.

If you have to do heavy work that for some reason can not be deferred, you should use `deferToThread()` to execute this work in a thread. See https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/core/howto/threading.html for details.

Comment: Still don't understand clearly: i thought `deferLater()` will first wait for some time (one sec in my case) and then executes, blocking the loop, no? I'll try `deferToThread()`

Comment: `deferLater()` just registers the call to be executed after the given time. It will return immediately. Your whole `render_GET` method will be executed in a few milliseconds. When the registered times of the execution arrives `make_delay()` will be called and it will block *everything* for 5 seconds. After that the callback `_delayedRender()` will finish the request.

Comment: `deferToThread()` produse same result. May be because of `NOT_DONE_YET`?

Comment: Running the current code example on the question, no, it doesn't produce the same result.  This is pasted directly from my shell:

```
    $ python webstuff.py &
    [1] 89589
    $ started httpserver...

    $ curl http://localhost:8880/social & curl http://localhost:8880/social &
    [2] 89591
    [3] 89592
    $ Sleeping
    Sleeping
    Sorry to keep you waiting.
    Sorry to keep you waiting.
    <html><body>Sorry to keep you waiting.</body></html><html><body>Sorry to keep you waiting.</body></html>
```

Comment: Funny thing: when I tested by opening 2 pages in browser it behaves like if it was singlethreaded, but if I open page in 2 different browsers, or corl - it is indeed threaded. Wonder why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use greenlents in your code (like threads).

You need to install the geventreactor - https://gist.github.com/yann2192/3394661

And use reactor.deferToGreenlet()

Also

In your long-calculation code need to call gevent.sleep() for change context to another greenlet.

```
msecs = 5 * 1000
timeout = 100
for xrange(0, msecs, timeout):
    sleep(timeout)
    gevent.sleep()
```